# Automatically notify me if a user from my office is returning and if the date has been set - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The task is to automatically notify me if a user from my office is returning and if the date has been set.

Basically, if a cell in column C (office) matches "Sydney" AND in the same row column I (return date) is not empty, I want to receive an e-mail notification.

Can anyone help me see what I'm missing here?

If I remove either of the conditions in the IF statement, it works as intended

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var mycell = ss.getActiveCell().activate();//Get the active cell. 
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();

// Get the full row of data, not just one cell
  var rowData = sheet.getSheetValues(cellrow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
// rowData is now a 2D array of Object (cell values), with a single row
// and sheet.getLastColumn() columns

// Here, only including the first and last names in the email
  var recipients = "x@x.com";
  var subject = "Employee" + rowData[0][0] + " " + rowData[0][1] +
  "(Row " + mycell.getRow() + ")";
  var body = rowData[0][0] + " " + rowData[0][1] + 
  "has just been added to the Office sheet on Row " + 
  mycell.getRow() + " To view them, visit: " + ss.getUrl();

//If column 5 isn't empty in sheet
  if ((cellcol == 3 && mycell.getValue() == "Sydney") && (cellcol == 9 && mycell.getValue() !=-1)) {
//Send the Email
   MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your if statement you say `cellcol` should be exactly `3` but also that it should be exactly `9`. That statement is always false and therefore the email will never be sent.

Comment: Perhaps you intented this`if ((cellcol == 3 && mycell.getValue() == "Sydney") || (cellcol == 9 && mycell.getValue() !=-1))`

Comment: @Cooper Does adding || to the if statement mean that the statement is true if one of the two conditions is true?
If so, I'm actually looking to ensure both conditions is met before the email is sent out

Comment: Well the problem with that is  that cellcol cannot equal 3 and 9 at the same time so it's never going to be true if you AND (&&) those two clauses together.  That's why I assumed that you didn't want it that way because you will never send any emails.